# Tag [fastner] should be [fastener] (missing an 'e')

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

There's a tag [fastner](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastner) on the site that is presumably a typo. It should be [fastener](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastener), which doesn't exist.

Can a mod please create the correctly-spelled version and synonymize the typo?

Comment: 'fastner' is still in the system. There are no questions attached to it, but the 14 questions attached to 'fastener' are linked to it. Can we delete it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done [fastner](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastner) is now [fastener](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastener)